# Сохранение позиции выбранного элемента в списке

Tags: java, android, коллекции

У меня есть список элементов. Я нажимаю на первый элемент и его порядковый номер становится 1. Потом я нажимаю на второй элемент - его порядковый номер - 2. На третий - 3 и так до 10. Затем я снова нажимаю на пятый и первый элементы и их порядковые номера удаляются. Не могу сделать, чтобы при повторном нажатии на пятый, а затем на первый элемент их порядковые номера стали 1 и 5 соответственно. И так по аналогии с произвольным количеством элементов и произвольным выбором порядковых номеров.

По контексту задачи: у меня есть набор карточек со значениями и мне нужно выбрать последовательность, в которой на следующем экране отображать эти карточки.

Comment: Размер списка известен заранее и не меняется?

Comment: @iksuy да, известен и не меняется.

Comment: А в чем проблема добавлять позиции в `ArrayList`? Если число уже есть, то удалять, если нет - добавлять.

Comment: @Flippy если я выберу 50 элементов, а потом уберу 2, то у меня 2 номера освободятся, потом мне нужно взять минимальный из этих 2-х, слишком много условий, я думал есть какой-то более изящный способ это сделать...

Comment: Коллекции автоматически меняют свои размеры и "дыр" не будет

Comment: Для нахождения минимального значения - `Collections.min(list);`

Comment: @Flippy мне дыры не страшны, мне нужно, чтобы нельзя было два раза добавить элемент с одинаковым номером в очереди

Comment: А нельзя просто использовать мультиселект `ListView` (`ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`) - тогда не надо будет отслеживать что удалено, что добавлено в ваш список - в конце операция получите список выбранных позиций и все

Comment: @Barmaley К сожалению, нет, у меня там список не `ListView` а просто в `LinearLayout` кастомные `View` кладутся

Comment: Тогда вам прямая дорога в `RecyclerView` - там ловить все проще

Comment: @Barmaley а как? У меня все кастомное и `View` счетчика кастомное...и место, куда отображать номер позиции тоже кастомные...Если предложите хотя бы абстрастный пример реализации, я буду очень рад ибо времени уже нет...

Comment: Если времени мало - то боюсь не уложитесь, лучше уж костыли с `ArrayList<MyBean>` где `MyBean` держит `id` и проч. причиндалы как в ответе @YuraIvanov

Comment: @Barmaley он не подходит, на сколько я понимаю. Мне нужно запоминать позиции из которых элементы удалены и новые элементы уже вставлять в эти дыры. А в `ArrayList` просто будет смещение

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> selectionList = new ArrayList<>();

void onClick(View v){
  Integer position = holder.getAdapterPosition();// для примера
  if(!selectionList.remove(position)) //удаляем 
      selectionList.add(position);    //и если нечего было удалять, добавляем в конец
}
```

**UPD**

```
List<MyItem> selectionList = new ArrayList<>();
void onClick(View v){
  int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();// для примера
  MyItem item = mItems.get(position);
  if(!selectionList.remove(item)) //удаляем 
      selectionList.add(item);    //и если нечего было удалять, добавляем в конец
}
```

**UPD2** Вариант с дырками

```
List<MyItem> selectionList = new ArrayList<>();
void onClick(View v){
    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();// для примера
    MyItem item = mItems.get(position);
    int index = selectionList.indexOf(item);
    if(index<0) { // элемент еще не добавлен
        index = selectionList.indexOf(null); //ищем дырки
        if(index<0) { // дырок нет
            selectionList.add(item);
        } else {
            selectionList.set(index, item);
        }
    } else { // элемент добавлен ранее, отжимаем
        selectionList.set(index, null); // делаем дырку
    }
}

List<MyItem> getSelectionList() { // когда понадобится список, надо удалить дырки
    List<MyItem> result = new ArrayList<>(selectionList); //копия списка
    Iterator<MyItem> it = result.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        if(it.next()==null) //удаляем дырки
            it.remove();
    }
    return result; // список без дырок
}
```

Comment: В данном случае метод `remove()` будет возвращать объект `Integer`, а не `boolean`, так как будет интерпретироваться как метод удаления по позиции.

Comment: @zTrap спасибо поправил.

Comment: @YuraIvanov спасибо за ответ, но, `ArrayList` мне не подходит, т.к. мне нужно сохранять еще и `id` элемента с его позицией в очереди

Comment: @AlexanderLomovskiy дополнил ответ. Список сам по себе нужен для хранения последовательности, а что конкретно в этом списке будет хранится не так важно. Это может быть MyObject, Pair<Integer, Integer>... Использования сайдэффекта TreeHashSet'а или TreeHashMap'а, сохраняющего порядок добавления элементов уж точно не проще.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Пока писал ответ, вы успели дополнить :D

Comment: @YuraIvanov я дико извиняюсь, может я уже просто пересидел и мозги не работают, но, если я сохраняю `id` в список, то последовательность их записи туда и есть мои номера в очереди. Но, если я удаляю через проверку `id` элемента, как мне потом вставить `id` другого элемента на то место, откуда был удален старый, чтобы последовательность в очереди запомнить?

Comment: @AlexanderLomovskiy Все-таки вам, наверное, надо уточнить постановку. В моем ответе очередь представлена элементами, на которые нажали нечетное количество раз, элементы на которые нажали четное количество раз, в очереди отсутствуют. Порядок элементов в очереди четко соответствует последовательности последних нечетных нажатий. `[]->1->[1]->2->[1,2]->3->[1,2,3]->2->[1,3]->4->[1,3,4]->3->[1,4]->2->[1,4,2]->...` Фраза "вставить id другого элемента на то место" вводит в заблуждение, вы хотите добавлять элементы вне очереди?

Comment: @YuraIvanov да, Вы правы, я плохо описал задачу. Я переформулировал ее, надеюсь, теперь станет понятнее...

Comment: @AlexanderLomovskiy добавил вариант с дырками

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы хранить `id` и позицию, можно создать класс-обёртку для выбранного элемента:

```
pulic class SelectedItem{
    private int id;
    private int position;

    public SelectedItem(int id, int position){
        this.position = position;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return position;
    }
}
```

При нажатии проверять коллекцию выбранных элементов на наличие `id` и при нахождении удалять:

```
List<SelectedItem> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();

private boolean haveInclusion(int id){
    List<SelectedItem> itemsForDelete = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!selectedItems.isEmpty()){
        for(SelectedItem item : selectedItems){
            if(item.getId() == id){
                itemsForDelete.add(item);
            }
        }
        if(!itemsForDelete.isEmpty()){
            selectedItems.removeAll(itemsForDelete);
        }
    }
    return !itemsForDelete.isEmpty();
}
```

И добавлять элемент по необходимости:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    int id = v.getId();//если необходимо проверять не id view-компонента передавайте его здесь
    if(!haveInclusion(id){
        selectedItems.add(new SelectedItem(id, position/*здесь передавайте позицию элемента*/);
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

Если использовать эту схему, то необходимо перед отправкой на отображение, просто отсортировать коллекцию по `position`

Comment: Нельзя так, получите ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: @YuraIvanov спасибо, исправил